# VBA: Content control; filename of a picture

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I'm relatively new to VBA & trying to automatize inserting a picture in several Word documents. So in the Word document I made a picture content control. I gave this content control the title "insert_pict". Now in my Macro, how can I add

I have this code so far:

```
Sub picturecc()

Dim Word_path As String
Dim Imagelocation As String
Word_path = "template.docm"
Imagelocation = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Picture1.png"
Documents(Word_path).Activate
With ActiveDocument
    .SelectContentControlsByTitle("insert_pict")(1).Range.InlineShape.AddPicture (Imagelocation)
End With

End Sub
```

But I get the error "method or data member not found" in the line .SelectContentControlsByTitle("insert_pict")(1).Range.InlineShape.AddPicture (Imagelocation). What is the right way to add the pricture to the content control? Can anyone help me out to get this work? Very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
With ActiveDocument
    .InlineShapes.AddPicture Imagelocation, , , .SelectContentControlsByTitle("insert_pict")(1).Range
End With
```